# Detect when task module is closed via the X or clicking off the task

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm using botbuilder 4 and botbuilder-teams node packages for my teams bot, is there any events sent to the bot when my task module gets dismissed by the user?  Either via the X or clicking off the dialog window?  I would like to clean up some conversation state when that happens.

Comment: Bot receives task/submit event when you [submit the result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/task-modules/task-modules-bots#submitting-the-result-of-a-task-module) of task module. There is no event received when you close the task module from X in bots. However, when you close the task module in tabs your app receives an [err](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/task-modules/task-modules-overview#what-a-task-module-looks-like) event.

Comment: @Gousia, you should post this as an answer.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT thanks, I'll see what I can do to work around it in other ways then

Answer (score 0):

If the task module is opening from the tab then you can get this information with the `submitHandler` `err` string. When user press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or click on <kbd>X</kbd>. It give error as "*User cancelled/close the task module*"

Have a look at code for reference:

```
microsoftTeams.tasks.startTask(taskInfo, (err: string, re: string) => { 
    if (err) {
        // It will execute this part if there's some error or user click on X button
        alert(err);
    }
});
```